# foreach on a Laravel collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I'm pretty confused, I need to make a loop from a Laravel collection to print it a table.

My collection looks like:

[image]

The loop that I'm trying to do is something like:

```
@foreach($entries as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $value->nombre }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/rgl/resultados/archivoerrors/{{$file["type"]}}/{{$file["nombre"]}}" class="btn btn-primary mr-5"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-download" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Download"></i> </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I'm having issues to read the collection on the loop, confused with the array-string-object concept. I need to read the 'nombre', 'path' and 'type'

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an array, so do this instead:

```
{{ $value['nombre'] }}
```

And:

```
{{ $value['type'] . '/' . $value['nombre'] }}
```